# Como transformar String para Float em Java, fazendo o arredondamento com math.round

Tags: java, string, matemática, float, java-11

eu preciso de ajuda com algo simples em Java. Meu conhecimento não é tão aprofundado e estou fazendo um projeto em que preciso receber o valor em String, mas depois fazer uma saída pro usuário com número inteiro, mas antes disso preciso fazer o arredondamento pois são numeros quebrado que quero transformar em inteiro!
Para tentar exemplificar o que estou dizendo, segue um trecho de código a seguir

```
    String valor = "1.8";
    Float valorFloat = Float.valueOf(valor);
    Math.round(valorFloat);
    System.out.println(valorFloat);
```

A minha saída está sendo 1.8, mas teria que ser 2 já que estou realizando o arredondamento, como posso fazer? Alguem sabe?
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Vc precisa pegar o retorno do método, por exemplo atribuindo a uma variável: `int valorArredondado = Math.round(valorFloat)`

Comment: Ou, se não quiser usar a variável, pode mostrar o retorno assim: `System.out.println(Math.round(valorFloat));` - O importante é entender que em geral, as funções recebem um valor dentro dos parênteses, e devolvem um NOVO resultado (usualmente não modificam o que foi passado). Este valor você usa conforme sua conveniência. Quando faz `a(b(c()))` é chamada a função c, seu resultado é usado pela função b, e o resultado da função b é usado por a. quando faz `variavel = func( )` está fazendo uma chamada para a função func, e DEPOIS atribuindo o valor retornado à variável.

Answer (score -1):

Quando voce utiliza o metodo Math.round(parametro) ele lhe retorna um valor que voce deve guardar em alguma variavel, e apos isso usar essa variavel para imprimir. Ou entao voce ja pode usar o system.out com o retorno do Math.round(), dessa forma:

```
String valor = "1.8";
Float valorFloat = Float.valueOf(valor);
System.out.println(Math.round(valorFloat));
```

Answer (score -3):

Se você deseja utilizar um número inteiro. Você deve fazer uma conversão do valor em `String` primeiro para `Double`, arrendondar o valor com o `Math.round`(o retorno deste método é um `long`) para no fim converter para `int` e guardar na variável.

Segue um exemplo simples:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String valor = "1.8";
    int valorInt = Integer.parseInt(Math.round(Double.parseDouble(valor)) + "");
    System.out.println(valorInt);
}
```